# Specific validation of input char array in C++

Tags: c++, validation

For some time I've had problem in correct validating char array. I've already seen many great ways to do this, but still didn't figured out how to combine few things in my code.
Can't figure out how to properly resolve this simple problem.

```
 struct student{
    char fullname[SLEN];
    char hobby[SLEN];
    int ooplevel;
    };

int getinfo( student*, int );
void display1( student );
void display2( const student* );
void display3( const student pa[], int );

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Group size: ";
    int class_size;
    std::cin >> class_size;
    while( std::cin.get() != '\n' )
        continue;

    student* ptr_stu = new student[class_size];
    int entered = getinfo( ptr_stu, class_size );
    for( int i=0; i<entered; ++i )
    {
        display1( ptr_stu[i] );
        display2( &ptr_stu[i] );
    }
    display3( ptr_stu, entered );
    delete [] ptr_stu;
    std::cout << "Gotowe.\n";

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int getinfo( student* stu, int n )
{
    int i=0;

    while( i<n ){

        std::cout << "Fullname " << i+1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> stu[i].fullname;

        std::cout << "Hobby " << i+1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> stu[i].hobby;

        std::cout << "OOPlevel " << i+1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> stu[i].ooplevel;
    ++i;
    }
}
```

I'm just sure that there must be  way to validate char array which:
1. Maximum length is 30
2. Must include 2 words, because its first and second name
3. Cannot include digits
4. Results in breaking the loop if user press enter without typing anything
5. And everything is in function which one of arguments is pointer to structure where names will be stored.
Forgive me for such primitive problem. I know that there isn't even attempt in my code to resolve this, but I've just didn't wanned to put trash I've created here.

Comment: Your code will be greatly simplified by making the 4 functions (getinfo(), display1(), display2(), and display3()) into methods of your class "struct students".

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Maximum length is 30

`std::cin >> std::setw(30) >> ...;`

> 2. Must include 2 words, because its first and second name

Bad luck with `operator>>`, it *will* stop at whitespace. So you either need to read *twice* or you read a complete line (`std::getline`).

> 3. Cannot include digits

Well, iterate over the string and check each character with `isdigit`:

```
for(unsigned char c : theString)
{
    if(isdigit(c))
        // error!
}
```

> 4. Results in breaking the loop if user press enter without typing anything

Again, bad luck with `operator>>` - it will simply ignore whitespace, including newlines... Again, you need `std::getline`:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
if(s.empty())
    break; // or return
```

Not sure if it is that a good idea, though, as the user might accidentially hit enter. And what about the user entering white space only? Line is non-empty, but still does not contain any information...

> 5. And everything is in function which one of arguments is pointer to structure where names will be stored.

Not sure what you mean by that - you have getInfo already, haven't you?

You might discover that not all above combines well, e. g. getting empty lines only works with `std::getline`, so you will have to use it all the time...

Now wondering - you use C++ - why don't you use the C++ standard containers? They make your live much easier:

```
struct Student
{
    std::string fullName; // I personally would prefere surname and forename anyway...
    std::string hobby;
    // ...
}

int getInfo(std::vector<Student>& students)
{
    for(auto& student : students)
    //      ^ enforce reference to actually modify the objects in the vector
    {
        // read input...
    }

    // you should return something!!!
    return students.size();
}
```

OK, for premature loop exit, we need a return value - we can profit from vector providinig contiguous memory, so the following is valid:

```
if(emptyLine)
    return &student - students.data();
```

Students full name:

```
// we don't need any additional buffer, can read into target directly...
std::getline(std::cin, student.fullName);
auto i = student.fullName.begin(), j = i;
while(isspace((unsigned char)(*i))
    ++i;
while(!isspace((unsigned char)(*i))
{
    if(isdigit((unsigned char)(*i))
        // error handling!
    *j++ = *i++;
}
*j++ = ' '; // separator
// now sure name analogously!
student.fullName.resize(j - student.fullName.begin());
```

You might have noticed: this reads in an entire string and modifies it in place. Like it?

There is yet **some error** in the code above, do you see it? It is essential to check for i `!= fullName.end()` in the while loops and before assigning the separating whitespace to make sure you do not exceed the string's current range! I'll leave that to you...

You should now use a vector for your display functions, too:

```
void display(std::vector const& students);
//          ^ no need for additional identifiers, C++ supports overloads
//                        ^ const vector, you won't modify it
//                            ^ reference to prevent a copy
```

Hint for the loop:

```
for(auto& student : students)
```

Using auto keyword prevents you from having to care for the objects being const or not. The reference then prevents you from copying the data, so this is what you should prefer...

Analogously for a single student:

```
void display(Student const& student);
//          ^ overload!
//                     ^  ^ const reference
```

In main:

```
//student* ptr_stu = new student[class_size];
//^ replaced by:
std::vector<Student> students(class_size);
//                   ^ or whatever name you like
//                            ^ one of vectors constructors accepts a size
//                              this is then equivalent to:
//                              std::vector<...> v; v.resize(n);
//                                               ^ (empty vector)
// and no need for deletion either...
```